# Multiple Sorts on same column on a table in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I have the following table:

Group Value

```
1. A       10
2. A       8
3. B       15
4. B       17  
5. B       16
6. C       20
7. C       5
8. C       6
9. D       12
10.E       10
```

I need have group C at the top, then sort by A-Z below, then overall sort by Value from largest to smallest in excel.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to define your own sorting criterion in Excel, there I'd propose another solution: create a function (seen the requierements I believe you'll need to it in VBA), that function calculates a value out of the input strings, you fill an extra helper column with those helper values, and then you sort that helper column.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a couple other ways to accomplish this.

(1) Create another column, put a "1" for rows where groupid = C, and "2" for all other rows. This can be a formula. Then sort by this column first, then group, then value.

(2) Change your group name. For example, change C to 1C. Or maybe change everything else to start with z.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own sort logic using `Custom lists`.To do this, follow these steps:

1. Go to `File -> Options -> Advanced`, scroll to `General` group, open `Edit custom lists` dialog.

[image]

2. Select `Custom lists` = `NEW LIST` and enter values `C, A-Z` inside `List entries`

[image]

3. Go back to worksheet and select `Home -> Sort & Filter -> Custom sort` dialog

[image]

4. Add the required column and a newly created custom sort in the `Order` section.
5. Add another columns

[image]